# how to use xrandr to mirror just a part of my main screen?

Tags: x11, monitors, xrandr, mirror

I want to make a mirror of just a part of my main screen to another monitor with different resolution. So it will be necessary to crop the desired area and apply a transformation to fit the screen area.

[image: mirros screen setup]